# eGerrit - Invalid URL

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gerrit

I'm trying to use the eGerrit Eclipse Plugin (https://www.eclipse.org/egerrit/) for connecting to my gerrit server out of Eclipse. Everytime I try to connect I get an error that my URL (https://gerrit.isys-software.de) is not valid. But I'm quite sure that the URL is valid, because I can call it in the browser without problems. Does someone use the eGerrit Plugin an can give me some advice?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The certificate couldn't be verified, following error was found in Eclipse-Log:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) at
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder$TrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextBuilder.java:190)  at
sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 84 more
```

Next step: Added the server certificate to a custom truststore via console:

```
keytool.exe -import -alias <alias> -file <path-to-certificate> -keystore <path-to-truststore>
```

After I started Eclipse with 2 truststore parameters, the connection could be established without problems.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path-to-truststore>
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```